# Missing formulas in broken homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

After doing a Ctrol+C on a 'brew update' command, can't see all available formulas (searching with brew search command, E.g any php package)
I've tried with brew doctor and cleanup commands without any luck.
How can I fix this without uninstalling brew and all its programs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering about this as well. I switched to an older version of scala, now the formula is missing and I can't install the latest version. I'm going to uninstall and reinstall homebrew for a quickfix for now.